# TINYMCE set focus... just will not work

Tags: javascript, focus, tinymce, set

I've tried

```
tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand("content", "mceFocus");
```

I've tried

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, "content");
```

None of them seem to work :-(

Comment: I tried this on Safari 5.0.4, Firefox 3.6.13 and Google Chrome 10.0 on Mac OSX 10.6.6 and IE 8 on Win XP using TinyMCE 3.4 with two "advanced" instances of Tiny. In all cases focus shifted to the specified instance. Can you elaborate on when you call these, what version of TinyMCE, Browser, OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I was stuck in the same problem. But I believe it depends where you execute the code. Here are various links that I've found so far:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8238

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=91307#p91307

But I solved my issue the following, and it might not apply to yours:

`this.focus();`

`this.tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'yourTinyMCEtextAreaID_goes_here');`

This code was applied inside the tiny_mce_src.js -> InsertHorizontalRule, just so you can have an idea of the scope.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

There is an even simpler way than the previous suggested code. When you initialize tinymce, there is an option to set the configuration parameters. Just make sure that you set the AUTOFOCUS option.

```
var editorOptions = {
    script_url: "/scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js",
    theme: "advanced",
    entities: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    content_css: "/styles/site.css",
    template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,help",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
    width: "640",
    height: "220",
    auto_focus: "body2"
};
```

Comment: This is by far the best response! Should be the real answer IMO.

Comment: Triggering focus is not the same as auto_focus. This might work when TinyMCE is initted, but that's it. This does not specifically answer the OPs question.