# tinymce table cell selection not working in IE9 but works fine in FireFox

Tags: select, tinymce, focus, selection

I have the following TinyMCE table plugin
The code in 'bold' focuses the cursor to next cell when TAB is pressed to navigate within the table. But unfortunately the blinking cursor is not displaying in IE9 but works in firefox

---

```
mceTableMoveToNextRow : function(val) {
                var currentCell = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'TD');
                var table = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'table')
                var nextCell;
                nextCell = ed.dom.getNext(currentCell, "td");
                if(nextCell == null) {
                    var currentRow = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'TR');
                    var nextRow = ed.dom.getNext(currentRow,"tr");
                    if(nextRow != null) {
                        nextCell = nextRow.cells[0];
                    }

                }
                if (!nextCell || nextCell == null) {
                    var currentRow = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'TR');
                    ed.execCommand("mceTableInsertRowAfter", currentCell);
                    var nextRow = ed.dom.getNext(currentRow,"tr");
                    nextCell = nextRow.cells[0];
                    **ed.selection.select(nextCell, true);**
                    //ed.selection.collapse(true);
                } else {
                    **ed.selection.select(nextCell, true);**
                }
                return false;
            },
```

Comment: when u say its not displaying in IE, does it mean that, the focus is not transferred to the next cell ?

Comment: yes the focus is not transferred to the next cell but the control has shifted to the next cell. Once i start typing in that particular cell, it'll start blinking. All this happens in IE9 while it works perfectly in Firefox.

Comment: my mistake. the code in 'bold' is supposed to focus the cursor to the next cell which isnt happening in case of IE9

Comment: I hope this SO could help you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310005/tinymce-set-focus-just-will-not-work?rq=1

Comment: Hey Thanks for the suggestiong but i tried that link as well. Any tinymce experts here?